# list_remove_unrelated_type - dart

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I have a function like this:

```dart
void function(List<int> listToRemove) {
  final List<int> list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  list.remove(listToRemove);
}
```

and its **Invocation of `remove` with references of unrelated types. dart(list_remove_unrelated_type)** error on list.remove(listToRemove).

I read https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/list_remove_unrelated_type.html this but still dont know how to initialize listToRemove. Anyone have idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have a **List<int>**, so you can use [remove](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-core/List/remove.html) to remove an **int** from this list.
You're trying to remove a **List<int>** from a **List<int>** which is why it throws a [list_remove_unrelated_type](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/list_remove_unrelated_type.html):
**"DON'T invoke remove on List with an instance of different type than the parameter type."**

If you want to remove **List<int>** from another **List<int>** you can try this:

```dart
void function(List<int> list, List<int> toRemove) {
  for(int item in toRemove){
    list.remove(item); // Removes the first occurrence of value from this list.
  }
}

void main() {
  List<int> list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  List<int> toRemove = [4, 1];
  function(list, toRemove);
  print(list); // [2, 3, 5]
}
```

Comment: Or use `.removeAll(list)`.

Comment: It seems to work with sets, not lists: 
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Set/removeAll.html

Comment: ACK, that was [never added](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/21866). Clearly an oversight. The equivalent to use, which does exist. is `.removeWhere(list.contains)` (for small lists) or `.removeWhere(list.toSet().contains)` (for large lists).